# Como descobrir o índice de uma DataRow pelo valor de uma coluna do DataTable

Tags: c#, combobox

Estou com uma dificuldade referente ao combobox, preciso setar um valor especifico para visualização, como se fosse a função de visualização de um cadastro já existente, o valor estará na variável que passei como parâmetro para a função; após a alimentação do combobox.

```
private void PreencherDados(Produto produto)
        {
            edtCodigo.Text = produto.Codigo.ToString();
            edtDescricao.Text = produto.Descricao.ToString();

            GruposNegocio gruposNegocio = new GruposNegocio(null);
            cbGrupo.Items.Clear();

           /*Alimentacao combobox, conforme o retorno do banco de dados*/
            foreach (DataRow item in gruposNegocio.Pesquisar().Rows)
            {
                Grupos grupos = new Grupos();
                grupos.Codigo = Convert.ToDouble(item["CODIGO"].ToString());
                grupos.Descricao = item["DESCRICAO"].ToString();
                cbGrupo.Items.Add(grupos);
            }

/* Neste momento preciso coletar o valor que vem da variavel produto.descrição, e setar o index da mesma no combobox*/

            cbGrupo.SelectedIndex = ;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não acho que faça sentido buscar um item por sua descrição ao invés de seu código... assim como o mapeamento da `DataTable` para o combo box poderia ser feito de forma mais prática... Mas segue um exemplo utilizando o `indexOf()`, já não está claro como é a estrutura da classe `Grupos`.

```
private void PreencherDados(Produto produto)
{
    edtCodigo.Text = produto.Codigo.ToString();
    edtDescricao.Text = produto.Descricao.ToString();

    GruposNegocio gruposNegocio = new GruposNegocio(null);
    cbGrupo.Items.Clear();

    var dataTable = gruposNegocio.Pesquisar();


    foreach (DataRow item in dataTable.Rows)
    {
        Grupos grupos = new Grupos();
        grupos.Codigo = Convert.ToDouble(item["CODIGO"].ToString());
        grupos.Descricao = item["DESCRICAO"].ToString();
        cbGrupo.Items.Add(grupos);
    }

    cbGrupo.SelectedIndex = dataTable
        .Rows
        .IndexOf(dataTable.Select($"DESCRICAO = '{produto.Descricao}'").ToList().FirstOrDefault() ?? 0);
}
```